# dojo.hitch() scope for window.setInterval()

Tags: javascript, dojo, scope

I am trying to produce a blinking effect using dojo fadeIn/Out.

The following snippet of code is defined inside the declaration of a widget class:

```
 _startHighlightEffect : function() {
      var blinkInterval = 5000; //Scope here is that of the parent widget
      window.setInterval ( function() {
              dojo.fadeOut(
              {
                      node: this._headerDiv.domNode,
                      onEnd: function() {
                              dojo.fadeIn({node: this._headerDiv.domNode},3000).play();
                      }
              },3000).play();
      }, blinkInterval);
  },

_highlightEffect : function() {
    this.func = dojo.hitch(this,this._startHighlightEffect);
    this.func();
}
```

The problem I am facing is that it says,"this._headerDiv is undefined". On checking with firebug, the scope of `this._headerDiv` is Window instead of the parent widget.

Please help me understand what am I missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can save the context when it is the context you want, and use it later:

```
_startHighlightEffect : function() {
      var blinkInterval = 5000; //Scope here is that of the parent widget
      var that = this; // save the scope
      window.setInterval ( function() {
              dojo.fadeOut(
              {
                      node: that._headerDiv.domNode, // use the saved scope
                      onEnd: function() {
                              dojo.fadeIn({node: that._headerDiv.domNode},3000).play();
                      }
              },3000).play();
      }, blinkInterval);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

What @jbabey describes will work, but in terms of `dojo.hitch`, you used it on the wrong function.  You need to hitch the function that is passed into `setInterval`.

```
_startHighlightEffect : function() {
  var blinkInterval = 5000; //Scope here is that of the parent widget

  // hitch the function that will be executed by the setInterval call *********
  window.setInterval (dojo.hitch(this, function() {
          dojo.fadeOut(
          {
                  node: this._headerDiv.domNode,
                  onEnd: dojo.hitch(this, function() {
                          dojo.fadeIn(
                                {node: this._headerDiv.domNode},3000).play();
                  })
          },3000).play();
  }, blinkInterval));
},

_highlightEffect : function() {
  this._startHighlightEffect();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to wrap the `onEnd` callback in a `dojo.hitch` also.